# How to change attribute from false to true (or true to false) by click on Angular

Tags: angular

I want to change value of attribute in boolean way by clicking on the component anywhere.So when i click its changed to true, and when i click another time its false and like that ...

Comment: @SilvanBregy That's `angularjs`, OP is looking for `angular` from their code

Comment: @Anurag Srivatava Hmm, i thought `angular` is just an alias for `angularjs` ..

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1**

You can create a variable like `public isLarge:boolean = false` in the parent component, and do something like that :

```
<lib-obe-latest-invoice 
    [largeLatestView]="isLarge" 
    (click)="isLarge = !isLarge">
</lib-obe-latest-invoice>
```

This "click" ouput is native with Angular.

**Solution 2**

Another solution is to do the job only in the component. So you can remove your input, and just have :

```
<lib-obe-latest-invoice><lib-obe-latest-invoice>
```

And inside LibObeLatestInvoiceComponent, add decoratore instead of your @Input.

Change :

```
@Input() largeLatestView: boolean
```

To :

```
largeLatestView = false;

@HostListener('click')
onClick() {
    this.largeLatestView = !this.largeLatestView;
}
```

The result will be the same.